# what's the relation between c++ client session and c_api TF_Session and core/public/session in tensorflow source code?

Tags: c++, session, tensorflow

what's the relation between c++ client session and c_api TF_Session and core/public/session in tensorflow source code?
I'm reading the source code of tensorflow,but I'm confused to found that there are many part about session,

1. tensorflow/c/c_api_internal.cc defined TF_Session
2. tensorflow/c/c_api_test.cc defined a class CSession
3. tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.cc
4. tensorflow/core/public/session.h

then what's exactly a 'session'?Where's the concrete 'run' function of session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function calls for `session.run()` are made in `tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc`.
The files in the `c` and the `cc` folder are for the C++ API of tensorflow. If you are starting to understand the code for session execution `direct_session.cc` and `direct_session.h` are the places to start out.

Comment: thanks a lot.But what's the various session really about?Besides is there any good tool to read the tensorflow tool efficiently?

Comment: The file `tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc` imports `tensorflow/core/public/session.h`. Basically `DirectSession` class is inherited from the `Session` class. If you want to follow the code execution you can add print statements using VLOG and compile from source.  You can ignore the `c` and `cc` folders for now, they are just for the C API by Tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks so much!I'll try it now!

Comment: hi,@Utkarsh Agarwal, how do you debug and read the tensorflow code ?I'm using bazel+vim+ctags,but it's kind of low efficiency to find complex c++ symbol correctly.